# Does my website freeze chrome on other people's macs as well?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard

I just noticed that opening my website on Chrome(v17.0.963.66) for Mac(Snow Leopard) will freeze the whole application and was wondering if that's just me or everyone else.

Seems like it does this on every link requested from my domain. + I haven't changed any apache configurations.

The website: [egegorgulu.com](http://egegorgulu.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. Tried on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.7.3) worked fine in chrome and safari.

Same chrome version as you installed on Mac.

Also tried on chrome in Win 7 and worked fine too.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Snow Leopard, same version of Chrome.